# Chrome vinyl tape in the UK?

Tags: product-recommendation

I am looking for something like chrome vinyl tape - adhesive, and with a silver, reflective surface:

[image: Chrome vinyl tape]

No matter how hard I look for this in the UK, only US suppliers are available. Could this tape be called something else in the UK? It doesn't have to be vinyl - but being adhesive and harder to tear than metal foil is required.

The plan is to make a reflector for a CFL bulb out of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [Fancy Tapes](http://www.fancy-tapes.co.uk/). They sell a product called [mirror tape](http://www.fancy-tapes.co.uk/store/product/6-1111/).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I got some from B&Q, it was in the section with insulation next to the Aluminium Thermal Foil.